# Function to determine whether or not a downloaded file is identical to an existing one

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, checksum

I'm developing a linux-program, that is supposed to parse a file downloaded from another computer or the internet, and collect information from that file. The program also has to re-download the file by routine, every n days/hours/minutes/whatever, and parse it again to keep updated in case the file has changed.

However, the process of parsing the file could require a lot of resources. Thus, I would like a function to check if the file has changed since last time it was downloaded. I imagine something like this example:

```
int get_checksum(char *filename) {
    // New prototype, if no such function already exists in standard C-libraries
    int result;           // Or char/float/whatever


    // ...


    return result;
}
int main(void) {

    char filename[] = { "foo.dat" };
    char file_url[] = { "http://example.com/foo.dat" }
    int old_checksum;     // Or char/float/whatever
    int new_checksum;     // Or char/float/whatever


    // ...


    // Now assume that old_checksum has a value from before:

    dl_file(filename, file_url);    // Some prototype for downloading the file
    if ((new_checksum = get_checksum(filename)) == -1) {
        // Badness
    }
    else {
        if (new_checksum != old_checksum) {
            old_checksum = new_checksum;
            // Parse the file
        }
        else {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }


    // ...


}
```

**Q1: Is there such a function as** `get_checksum` **(from the example above) available in standard C/C++ libraries?**

**Q2: If not: What is the best way to achieve this purpose?**

There is no need for:
- a very advanced function
- encrypted or secured checksums
- the ability to compare a new file against files older than the last one, since the new downloaded file will always overwrite the older one

Comment: Can the file timestamps not be trusted?

Comment: @CareyGregory Won't the timestamps be altered when a new file is downloaded?

Comment: I was thinking you could get the timestamps from the source computer before downloading. If you could do that you could even skip the download.

Comment: Why not just fork and exec `sha1sum` or `md5sum`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stat()` function. It can give you access to the file parameters like last access time, **time of last modification**, file size etc:

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
    time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

But you need to have execute permission on the file you would be using it on.

[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

Comment: But won't the "last access time" and "last modification time" change every time the file is overwritten by a new download?

Comment: Yes, it would, in that case, you can use the `st_size` to check the file size, in case it was modified. Or any other parameter that might suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an XOR hash, in which you just xor successive blocks of unsigned ints/longs, but this has problems with collisions. For example, if the file is mostly chars, then the majority of the bytes will be in the ranges of normal ASCII/Unicode chars, so there will be a lot of unused key space.

For a standard implementation, you could read the file into a string and use std::hash from C++11. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

The following is an example of the first method:

```
unsigned int hash(vector<char> file){
    unsigned int result;
    int *arr = (int*)file.data();

    for(int i = 0;i < file.size() / sizeof(unsigned int);i++)
        result ^= arr[i];

    return result;
}
```

You just have to read the file into the vector.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're going to write that XOR hash then you can easily upgrade it to a DJB hash or similar, it's a one-line change. That basically gets you to where you'd want `std::hash<string>` to be.

Comment: Some implementations of std::hash for std::string are very weak - e.g. microsoft's used to (and may well still) pick 10 characters evenly spaced along the string to incorporate - all other characters ignored.  May still be sufficient, but it depends on the types of modifications the file is known to undergo.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing built in the C++ language until std::hash<> in C++11 which is very simple, but may be appropriate for your needs.

Last I checked there is nothing at all in Boost (the most common C++ library extension).  The reasoning is talked about here, but may be dated:

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/528553-why-doesnt-boost-have-a-cryptographic-hash-library/

So, you're best bet is:

[std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) with the file contents.

Or something like the following could be of use saved into a simple header and linked:

http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function

Or you could get a library such as [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html) or [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/).